# How to go from Tunis to Hammamet fast?

Tags: public-transport, taxis, tunisia

I need to be in Yasmine Hammamet early in the morning. Around 09:30, so taking the train is not a possibility.

I've read that there are buses going from Tunis to Hammamet, but I couldn't find any other info about this. Where to they depart from? Where do they stop? How long does the trip cost?

I've thought getting a Bolt or taxi, given that it seems to be under 20 euros, but I can't figure if that's realistic or drivers will refuse to make such a long trip. Is this possible?

Comment: Is going to Hammamet the previous day and staying overnight an option?

Comment: But Tunis to Hammamet is under an hour by taxi (66km), I doubt you'll have any trouble finding a driver, particularly if you can book with someone the previous day.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal for taxi or bolt drivers to refuse intercity travel. The best bet is to take an 8 people van/taxi also called (louage) from:

- Bab Saadoun terminal (destination: Bizerte, le Kef, Tabarka, Béja)
- Bab Alioua terminal (destination: Hammamet, Nabeul, Kelibia, Zaghouan)
- Moncef Bey terminal (destination: Sousse, Monastir, El Jem, Mahdia, Sfax, Gabès, Sidi Bouzid).

The price is usually 7 Tunisian dinars for 1h of travel.